# How to spin/rotate the wall

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

with the reference image i want to rotate / spin the wall, I tried with the spin tool but not working with me, any suggestion how it works, Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a circle, delete the vertices you don't need and move/scale into place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just set the 3d cursor to here and only select the last vertex:

[image]

[image]

then it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a question, what to fix manually the pivot point, any perfect angle

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - maybe open a new question for that to be clear and others could learn from it too?

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply bevel the corner and increase the number of segments with the mousewheel? You'd need to make sure that the scale of the object has been applied first (Ctrl-A > Scale in object mode).

Comment: @JohnEason: come on, that's too simple. Blender isn't simple :D

Comment: It's as complicated as you want to make it judging by the other answers! :^)